# Reading desktop plist

Tags: cocoa, macos

I am using following code to read the details of the plist,

```
NSString *plistPath = @"~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.desktop.plist";
NSDictionary *plistData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
```

But plistData has no entries.

Is there something wrong in above code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need expanding the tilde. Try this:

```
NSString * plistPath = [@"~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.desktop.plist" stringByExpandingTildeInPath];
```